# Can a person exist that isn't labelled with any "isms"?

Tags: existence

I've seen people complain about "isms" as if they are above isms. But people don't get to choose their labels. If they believe that everything that isn't the norm counts as an ism and should be avoided, they still believe in capitalism and whatnot, whether they want to admit that that's what supporting the norm entails or not. Is there a scenerio where someone could be totally void of isms? Would that make any sense?

Comment: Indeed 'ism' could be said to be nothing else but the good old Platonic forms unshakable for many, people may think or believe they can freely choose or select but merely remember either self-consistent or inconsistent histories per Plato if not all the time. There's a view called ontological nihilism which strictly speaking is not a 'ism', at least in its colloquial sense...

Comment: People complain about "isms" because those are overused and abused as loaded invectives, not because they go all abstract and make grandiose generalizations about not falling under any "ism" whatsoever. So what is the point of this [strawman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man)?

Comment: No, you can literally search 'the problem with isms' and find multiple articles that say exactly that. Either their saying, 'all isms are bad except mine' (but then why talk about the problem with isms in general) or are they are talking nonsense. Or is there a specific scenario where such talk would make sense, which is what I'm asking.

Comment: e.g., https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-problem-with-ideology-i-e-isms, like what, there are people that can exist without ideologies? They actually believe, 'everyone has ideology but me'? Sounds ridiculous, I'm not sure when that ever can make sense.

Comment: If they aren't all making a generalized statement, it'd be quite the coincidence. They are the ones making these statements, I'm just asking if it makes any sense, since I doubt any are saying, 'the problem with me'

Comment: What you can "literally search" is of little consequence because people routinely make rhetorical exaggerations when complaining in public. You have to look at context and what they are complaining about specifically, public rhetoric is not meant to be taken literally.

Comment: That sounds like a convenient thing to say.

Comment: It is nice when something true is also convenient, but is it here? It requires you to do more work to ask a meaningful question than simply quote a phrase and run with it. Phrases taken out of context rarely mean much. For example, instead of coming up with a caricature you could ask which uses of "isms" are legitimate, and how to distinguish them from widespread abuse.

Comment: I'm not going to read every article that makes this claim. I don't see any reason to think what you're saying is true. And even if there were a grain of truth, it's highly misleading for them to make such claims anyways.  I'm just repeating the claims I've seen and heard.

Comment: You can make a sweeping answer that explains the discrepancy with references if you want.'

Comment: It seems thT you are conflating belief with "-isms". Beliefs are unavoidable and useful. Classifying according to "-isms" is not so common.

Comment: "people don't get to choose their labels" - they do and they don't. There are people who e.g. reject the label of "atheist" (but rather "agnostic"), even though they meet the definition of it. As for whether it's possible that someone to not meet the definition of any "-ism", that's basically asking whether there's no set of -isms that's exhaustive (i.e. includes all humans). I think there definitely are exhaustive sets. For example, if you believe in a god, you're a theist. If you don't, you're an atheist. If you don't know, you're agnostic. It seems unavoidable to be one of those 3.